# Extract all video frames as images with FFMPEG

Tags: image, batch-file, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a MP4 video file into a series of jpg images (out-1.jpg, out-2.jpg etc.) using FFMPEG with,

```
mkdir frames
ffmpeg -i "%1" -r 1 frames/out-%03d.jpg
```

However I keep getting errors like,

> [image2 @ 00000037f5a811a0] Could not open file :
>   frames/out-C:\Applications\FFMPEG\toGIF.bat3d.jpg
>   av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error frame=    1 fps=0.0
>   q=5.9 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A video:63kB audio:0kB
>   subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
>   unknown Conversion failed!

If I take out the %03d part, the conversion works but it only outputs the first frame and the program stops with error.

How can I correctly extract all the frames of the video with FFMPEG?

Comment: You should use 
ffmepg -i input.mp4 -c:v png output_frame%04d.png 
for native conversion/better quality.
See: https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-movie-to-single-pictures_003f

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i "%1" frames/out-%03d.jpg
```

A sequence of image files don't have a framerate. If you want to undersample the video file, use `-r` before the input.

**Edit**:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Applications\FFMPEG\aa.mp4" "frames/out-%03d.jpg"
```

Comment: Okay found the issue finally, it seems that Windows needs %%, as in out-%%03d.jpg

Comment: Yes, it's a Windows .bat file

Comment: Yes, in a script, you need to escape special characters.

Comment: How can I get the frames as .h264 ?

Comment: to [change framerate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Framerates) before `-i`, enter `-framerate`. To specify framerate for output after `-i` enter `-r`

Comment: You should use 
ffmepg -i input.mp4 -c:v png output_frame%04d.png 
for native conversion/better quality.
See: https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-movie-to-single-pictures_003f

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mpg -r 1/1 $filename%03d.bmp
```

or

```
ffmpeg\ffmpeg -i file.mpg test\thumb%04d.jpg -hide_banner
```

Note:

1. to change framerate before `-i`, enter `-framerate`. To specify framerate for output after `-i` enter `-r`
2. `-filter:v -fps=fps=...` or `-vf fps=...` is more accurate than `-r`

eg.

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.avi -vf fps=<NO. of images>/<per no. of seconds> img%0<padding No. of digits>d.jpg
```

Comment: what is the difference between %04d and %03d?

Comment: %04d -> 4 digits (0000, 0001, 0002, etc)
%03d -> 3 digits (000, 001, 002, etc).

Comment: @CristianSepulveda: The answer to your question is in the provided code sample: "-vf fps=<`NO. of images`>/<`per no. of seconds`> img%0<`padding No. of digits`>d.jpg". Good job JavDomGom

Comment: It worked , but the output images are in low quality compared to video. Any fix for that?

Answer (score 2):

%04d will produce image-names with 4 digits like 0001, 0002 etc. And %03d will produce images with names like 001, 002 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use for native conversion/better quality:

```
ffmepg -i input.mp4 -c:v png output_frame%04d.png
```

See: https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-movie-to-single-pictures_003f

Batch script example for multiple video files:

```
@echo off

set ffmpeg=.\ffmpeg-6.1.1-full_build\bin\ffmpeg.exe

set pathVideos=.\pathVideos
set pathPNG=.\pathPNG

set videos=file1 file2 file3 file4

if not exist "%pathPNG%\" mkdir "%pathPNG%"

FOR %%V IN (%videos%) DO (
    %ffmpeg% -i "%pathVideos%\%%V.mp4" -c:v png "%pathPNG%\%%V_frame%%05d.png"
)
```

Answer (score -4):

Impossible to do in a windows batch file because every %x are interpreted as prameters passed to batch file

Comment: "Impossible" is such a harsh word... Easy to overcome: escape the `%` with another`%`: `%%x` works (as the asker already found out [7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786669/extract-all-video-frames-as-images-with-ffmpeg#comment57319040_34786929)).